# Android - Custom Listview - JSONArray - ArrayAdapter choose always the last

Tags: java, android

At first sorry if my English is bad, I'm a german guy.
So this is my Problem:
I want to make a Weather App, and now I'm working on the Forecast-Part.
I use a ArrayList, to save all the days with the weather temporary.
But int the App, he uses always the last Item of the ArrayList, and I can't find the problem.

So here is a Part of my Code:

```
     LinearLayout linearLayout;
private ArrayList<ForeCastWeather> list = new ArrayList<>();
CustomListAdapter adapter;
ListView listView;
View rootView;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.forecast_layout, container, false);

    return rootView;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    try {

        JSONObject json = ForecastWeatherData.getJsonObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("list");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject temp = jsonObject.getJSONObject("temp");
            JSONArray weather = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
            JSONObject weather_Object = weather.getJSONObject(0);

            ForeCastWeather foreCastWeather = new ForeCastWeather();

            foreCastWeather.setDt(jsonObject.getLong("dt"));

            foreCastWeather.setDay(temp.getDouble("day"));
            foreCastWeather.setMin(temp.getDouble("min"));
            foreCastWeather.setMax(temp.getDouble("max"));
            foreCastWeather.setNight(temp.getDouble("night"));
            foreCastWeather.setEve(temp.getDouble("eve"));
            foreCastWeather.setMorn(temp.getDouble("morn"));

            foreCastWeather.setPressure(jsonObject.getDouble("pressure"));
            foreCastWeather.setHumidity(jsonObject.getInt("humidity"));

            foreCastWeather.setID(weather_Object.getInt("id"));
            foreCastWeather.setMain(weather_Object.getString("main"));
            foreCastWeather.setDescription(weather_Object.getString("description"));
            foreCastWeather.setIcon(weather_Object.getString("icon"));

            foreCastWeather.setSpeed(jsonObject.getDouble("speed"));
            foreCastWeather.setDeg(jsonObject.getInt("deg"));
            foreCastWeather.setClouds(jsonObject.getInt("clouds"));
            try {
                foreCastWeather.setRain(jsonObject.getDouble("rain"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                foreCastWeather.setRain(0.0);
            }
            list.add(foreCastWeather);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    adapter.setData(list);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

This is my Adapter:

```
 private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<ForeCastWeather> foreCastWeathers;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<ForeCastWeather> foreCastWeathers) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.foreCastWeathers = foreCastWeathers;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return foreCastWeathers.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return foreCastWeathers.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (layoutInflater == null)
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
    TextView temp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
    TextView temp_max = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temp_min);
    TextView temp_min = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temp_max);
    TextView rain = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rain);
    TextView strange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wind);
    TextView degree = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deg);
    TextView clouds = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cloud);
    TextView humidity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.humid);
    TextView pressure = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.press);
    ForeCastWeather foreCastWeather = foreCastWeathers.get(position);

    try {
        time.setText(foreCastWeather.getDt() + "");
        temp.setText(foreCastWeather.getDay() + "");
        temp_max.setText(foreCastWeather.getMax() + "");
        temp_min.setText(foreCastWeather.getMin() + "");
        rain.setText(foreCastWeather.getRain() + "");
        strange.setText(foreCastWeather.getSpeed() + "");
        degree.setText(foreCastWeather.getDeg() + "");
        clouds.setText(foreCastWeather.getClouds() + "");
        humidity.setText(foreCastWeather.getHumidity() + "");
        pressure.setText(foreCastWeather.getPressure() + "");

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {


    }

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Jonah

Comment: "...he uses the last item..." - who is "he"? The `ListView`?

Comment: Can you show how you are attempting to use this list? I believe the list have all the foreCastWeather instances added properly.

Comment: @tambykojak, thats right

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this code live in your `Activity`, what I think you're missing is assigning the new data to the adapter. You're notifying the adapter that the data has changed using `notifyDataSetChanged()`, but the data the adapter is using probably hasn't changed.

In the `getView()` method of the adapter, where is the data being using to represent the list coming from? If it's a global variable inside the adapter class, then you have to create some way to set the adapter's list to the newly formed list... AND THEN call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

In your adapter, add this method:

```
public void setData(List<ForeCastWeather> newList) {
    foreCastWeathers = newList;
}
```

And then after after your `for` loop,

```
adapter.setData(list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Something I actually like to do is just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of the `setData()` method, but I've heard some complaints about that as well.

So in the end your activity would look like this:

```
    try {
        JSONObject json = ForecastWeatherData.getJsonObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("list");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject temp = jsonObject.getJSONObject("temp");
            JSONArray weather = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather");
            JSONObject weather_Object = weather.getJSONObject(0);

            ForeCastWeather foreCastWeather = new ForeCastWeather();

            foreCastWeather.setDt(jsonObject.getLong("dt"));

            foreCastWeather.setDay(temp.getDouble("day"));
            foreCastWeather.setMin(temp.getDouble("min"));
            foreCastWeather.setMax(temp.getDouble("max"));
            foreCastWeather.setNight(temp.getDouble("night"));
            foreCastWeather.setEve(temp.getDouble("eve"));
            foreCastWeather.setMorn(temp.getDouble("morn"));
            foreCastWeather.setPressure(jsonObject.getDouble("pressure"));
            foreCastWeather.setHumidity(jsonObject.getInt("humidity"));
            foreCastWeather.setID(weather_Object.getInt("id"));
            foreCastWeather.setMain(weather_Object.getString("main"));
            foreCastWeather.setDescription(weather_Object.getString("description"));
            foreCastWeather.setIcon(weather_Object.getString("icon"));
            foreCastWeather.setSpeed(jsonObject.getDouble("speed"));
            foreCastWeather.setDeg(jsonObject.getInt("deg"));
            foreCastWeather.setClouds(jsonObject.getInt("clouds"));

            try {
                foreCastWeather.setRain(jsonObject.getDouble("rain"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                foreCastWeather.setRain(0.0);
            }

            list.add(foreCastWeather); // we're adding the new object to this list, not the list in the adapter.
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    adapter.setData(list); // this is the important addition
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and your adapter like this:

```
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private List<ForeCastWeather> foreCastWeathers;

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<ForeCastWeather> foreCastWeathers) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.foreCastWeathers = foreCastWeathers;
    }

    /**
     * The addition is here
     */
    public void setData(List<ForeCastWeather> newList) {
        this.foreCastWeathers = newList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return foreCastWeathers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return foreCastWeathers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (layoutInflater == null)
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        TextView time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
        TextView temp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temp);
        TextView temp_max = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temp_min);
        TextView temp_min = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.temp_max);
        TextView rain = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rain);
        TextView strange = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wind);
        TextView degree = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deg);
        TextView clouds = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cloud);
        TextView humidity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.humid);
        TextView pressure = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.press);
        ForeCastWeather foreCastWeather = foreCastWeathers.get(position);

        try { // you shouldn't really need this try catch.
            time.setText(foreCastWeather.getDt() + "");
            temp.setText(foreCastWeather.getDay() + "");
            temp_max.setText(foreCastWeather.getMax() + "");
            temp_min.setText(foreCastWeather.getMin() + "");
            rain.setText(foreCastWeather.getRain() + "");
            strange.setText(foreCastWeather.getSpeed() + "");
            degree.setText(foreCastWeather.getDeg() + "");
            clouds.setText(foreCastWeather.getClouds() + "");
            humidity.setText(foreCastWeather.getHumidity() + "");
            pressure.setText(foreCastWeather.getPressure() + "");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is not the right way :(, but maybe I'm to stupid ;)

Comment: What is causing you to think that? Maybe I can help explain. Or maybe I can be enlightened :D.

Comment: Ok, you say existingList and newList, but I only use one List i think, so i have tried to implement your code, but then, I have nothing in my ListView :(

Comment: Now that you've posted your adapter code, let me update the answer.

Comment: Okay, updated. Do you see how you have a separate list in the adapter? The one named `foreCastWeathers`? The `ListView` and the adapter are using that data set, but when you create the new objects, you aren't adding them to `foreCastWeathers`, you're adding them to `list`, wherever that is defined.

Comment: ok i have found the problem why he shows nothing, but it's the same problem now. He's showing the same :(